# Regular expression - secong group of digits

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I would like to pull second group of digits which are after (`-`) from below string:

```
D:\data\home\Logs_Audit\VO12_LAB_20140617-000301.txt
```

I used `\d{8}` to pull `20140617` but now I want to pull **`000301`**

EDIT 1:

Now I would Like to pull `VO12_LAB` from above string. Could You please help me.
I am not good at regular expression and I didn't find good tutorial to understand it.

EDIT 2:
I found that something like

```
\w{2,3}\d{2,3}_\w{2,3}
```

works to me. Do you think it is accurate enough?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but if you use the single regex `\d+`, you can get all the digits in the path above in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookahead** for this.

```
\d+(?=\.)
```

**Explanation**: This matches digits (`1` or more times) preceded by a dot `.`

```
\d+          digits (0-9) (1 or more time)
(?=          look ahead to see if there is:
  \.           '.'
)            end of look-ahead
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pA4zZ1)

**Final Solution**:

```
String s = @"D:\data\home\Logs\V_LAB_20140617-000301.txt";
Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+(?=\.)");
if (m.Success) {
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value); //=> "000301"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Could you please explain it to me? \d+ means one or more digits, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead/lookbehind to find the group based on "anchors", like this:

```
(?<=[-])\\d+(?=[.]txt)
```

The groups before and after the `\\d+` are non-capturing zero-width "markers", in the sense that they do not consume any characters from the string, only describe character combinations that need to precede and/or follow the text that you would like to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=-)(\d+)
```

The first group will contain the digits.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vI9rP5)